# RTL8852BE, ubuntu 22.04: realtek manual driver installation throws error after system update

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, realtek

I've been following this [gh-repo](https://github.com/HRex39/rtl8852be.git) to manually install Realtek drivers on Ubuntu (22.04).

My understanding so far is that this specific card is not being properly "recognized" by Linux, so manual driver installation is a workaround.
Over the past months, after each kernel update the issue would re-emerge and on dir `rtl8852be` I would re-run the following commands:

```
make clean
make
sudo make install
```

Ubuntu would recognize the Network Card again and everything would work just fine.
Today, after Ubuntu update, on system reboot I got the expected problem. Followed the usual steps, but on

```
make
```

got the following unexpected error:

```
#rm -f .symvers.8852be
make ARCH=x86_64 CROSS_COMPILE= -C /lib/modules/5.19.0-32-generic/build M=/home/user/rtl8852be  modules
make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic'
warning: the compiler differs from the one used to build the kernel
  The kernel was built by: x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  You are using:           gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0
  CC [M]  /home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_cache_wback’:
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:21:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_dma_sync_single_for_device’; did you mean ‘dma_sync_single_for_device’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   21 |                 pci_dma_sync_single_for_device(hwdev, *bus_addr, size,
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 dma_sync_single_for_device
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_cache_inv’:
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:30:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_dma_sync_single_for_cpu’; did you mean ‘dma_sync_single_for_cpu’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   30 |                 pci_dma_sync_single_for_cpu(hwdev, *bus_addr, size, direction);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 dma_sync_single_for_cpu
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_get_bus_addr’:
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:39:29: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_map_single’; did you mean ‘dma_map_single’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   39 |                 *bus_addr = pci_map_single(hwdev, vir_addr, size, direction);
      |                             ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                             dma_map_single
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_unmap_bus_addr’:
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:50:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_unmap_single’; did you mean ‘dma_unmap_single’? [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   50 |                 pci_unmap_single(hwdev, *bus_addr, size, direction);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
      |                 dma_unmap_single
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c: In function ‘pci_free_noncache_mem’:
/home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.c:97:17: error: implicit declaration of function ‘pci_free_consistent’ [-Werror=implicit-function-declaration]
   97 |                 pci_free_consistent(pdev, size, vir_addr, *bus_addr);
      |                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
cc1: some warnings being treated as errors
make[2]: *** [scripts/Makefile.build:257: /home/user/rtl8852be/platform/platform_linux_pc_pci.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [Makefile:1850: /home/user/rtl8852be] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-5.19.0-32-generic'
make: *** [Makefile:637: modules] Error 2
```

I'm very little knowledgeable in Linux and C, so I thank you in advance for your patience.
At the moment I can't connect using the WI-FI.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: That driver doesn't build with the new 5.19 kernel. You need to find something else.

Comment: You can boot with a previous kernel and Wi-Fi should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Pilot6 says, that driver doesn't build with the new 5.19 kernel. I suggest that you delete the rtl8852be directory from your system. Next, with a temporary ethernet connection, tethering or whatever means possible, do:

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89.git
cd rtw89
make
sudo make install
```

Reboot. You should be all set.

Comment: This will be set till the next kernel upgrade ;-)

Comment: It worked, thank you so much for your invaluable support!
On a side note: @Pilot6, what previous version of the kernel would you recommend me to boot? Or is _any_ previous version just fine? 
Just making sure I don't mess up my linux partition :-)

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour The searchers will appreciate it.